# Successful Adaptive Payments Pay Request via paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a pay request via paypal sandbox.  When I execute the PHP, I get a success response.  However, I can't follow the transaction in the sandbox portal anywhere.

I'm using my API credentials from the sandbox (Which are working).  Here's the response I'm getting

> object(stdClass)#6 (3) { ["responseEnvelope"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4) { ["timestamp"]=> string(29) "2013-04-02T11:56:35.221-07:00" ["ack"]=> string(7) "Success" ["correlationId"]=> string(13) "30317d69b575d" ["build"]=> string(7) "5563463" } ["payKey"]=> string(20) "AP-8VN625716X0611726" ["paymentExecStatus"]=> string(7) "CREATED" }

Here's the request.  I've changed the email but it is set to an email that I have a sandbox account setup for.

> object(PayRequest)#4 (7) { ["requestEnvelope"]=> object(RequestEnvelope)#1 (2) { ["detailLevel"]=> NULL ["errorLanguage"]=> NULL } ["actionType"]=> string(3) "PAY" ["cancelUrl"]=> string(19) "http://www.ebay.com" ["currencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" ["memo"]=> string(10) "simple pay" ["receiverList"]=> object(ReceiverList)#2 (1) { ["receiver"]=> object(Receiver)#3 (2) { ["amount"]=> string(3) "3.0" ["email"]=> string(17) "xxx@gmail.com" } } ["returnUrl"]=> string(19) "http://www.ebay.com" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting a successful response with the PayKey, you would redirect the customer to:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=VALUE

Where VALUE is the PayKey you received in the API response.

Have you gone to this URL and continued the checkout with a Personal sandbox account?

Comment: OK, I actually found out my senderEmail wasn't provided on an implicit send.